# Is it possible to somehow modify value system maintained field in MS CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I'm trying to accomplish a rather strange task.  I'm required to change the value of the `IsDefault` attribute on a `Team` entity and after some manipulation return it back.

I tried updating the value using a C# plugin, a custom workflow step and the web-interface, however it seems to be not permitted in any case, no matter which user privileges I'm using to perform this operation. The system shows no exceptions, just happily ends with no error message.

Changing field value directly in `MS SQL` does work, but I may not always have direct access to it, and it's definitely the most dangerous approach since it is not technically supported.

Is there any workaround for this situation? Any way that I can update the System Maintained field in MS CRM 2011?

Comment: curiosity: which kind of logic can require to change that field?

Comment: @GuidoPreite, sad reasons, obviously. I need to implement three-dimensional hierarchy of business units. I mean, currently CRM supports one dimensional hierarchy model. And now imagine, I need to have two more users / units hierarchy alongside of standard. I know well that it is not supported. So I need to find a way around. Sharing on teams might help, but it disregards hierarchy (heads of superior BUs should see that records shared on given BU). So I'm trying not to add more teams to share, but add that heads into default team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a business unit automatically CRM create a default team with the same name and the property `IsDefault` set to true.

It's by design, in this way there is always a team that holds all the users from the business unit.

There isn't a supported way to change that value.